# AngularJS: Difference between $route and $routerProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can anyone explain me difference between `$route`and `$routeProvider`?

Comment: I think you mean `$route`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Services are singletons. They are instantiated the first time they are needed. Sometimes you have to configure a service before running it, for example in the `.config` part of the application module. This is where you use `$routeProvider`. After this, you can use the service instance (e.g. `$route`) normally, for example in the `.run` block of the app module.
Notice that with `$routeProvider` you define the routes (a configuration) and with `$route` you use methods that depend on the configuration.

There are three ways of defining services: the simplest is using `service`, then you can also use a `factory` and, if you need complex configuration, you use a `provider` [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provide-vs-factory)

Answer (score 2):

As @elclanrs pointed out, there's not $router that I know of. So I presume you mean the difference between **$route** and **$routeProvider**

The $route is used to deep-link URLs to Controllers and Views. It watches the location urls and tries to map it to existing paths. The $route is configured(defined) with the $routeProvider.

Here is the official documentation [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) , [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider)

Comment: yes, of course I've read docs. For me unclear such naming. Because if we look at other providers we can see that each has "name" and "nameProvide" - that is private function and just link to the "name"